# Replace and append part of a String - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

In my table I have a field "youtube" where the user can add a Youtube or Vimeo link. The Youtube links can be played directly, the Vimeo links which looks like:

```
https://vimeo.com/22614651XX
```

needs to be replaced by:

```
https://player.vimeo.com/video/22614651XX
```

Can this be done with SQL or should it be done in PHP? In PHP I found the substr() Function where I can split a string, but I have no clue how to deal with the numbers as they can vary in length...

Comment: If the urls are well formed the simplest thing is a single dumb `replace()`/`str_replace()` swapping `https://vimeo.com/` for  `https://player.vimeo.com/video/`

Comment: MySQL's REPLACE function or  PHP's  str_replace function should to the trick just fine.

Comment: Something like `REPLACE(column, 'https://vimeo', 'https://player.vimeo')` should do it. Use that with an `update` if you want it stored that way.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your assistance :-)

```
UPDATE wp_awa_upload
SET youtube = REPLACE(youtube, 'https://vimeo.com/', 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/')
WHERE youtube like "%vimeo%"
```

does the trick :-)

Kind Regards,

Stefan